# Asynchronous writes to a file in R

Tags: r, asynchronous

Could anyone provide me with some guidance on how to asynchronous writes from chunks of a very large file, each of which is being processed with the same function in a number of clusters (8-500). The file is approx 25 GB, so too large to fit in memory.

We are currently using the 'snow(fall)' and 'mmap' packages, but aren't able to get through some bottlenecks. Synchronous writes work fine, but asynchronous writes would be much more efficient.

I'm not sure what more information you need, but please feel free to ask me!

Comment: I just found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396632/asynchronous-network-io-using-r-any-existing-packages?rq=1 

If there is any extra information anyone can provide, please do let me know!

Comment: why don't you tell us some about your file?  Also I don't understand the correlation between 'large files' and 'asynchronous writes' - explain.

Comment: The files are 25GB (extending up to TB eventually) raster images. The idea is that because they are so large, splitting them into as many clusters as possible is the way to go. And asynchronous I/O is the way we are heading.

If the size and asynchronicity are un-correlated, forgive me...I might have some basic misunderstanding of the whole issue!

EDIT: The idea might be that we want to start processing bytes of the image as soon as they are written to disk without waiting for other clusters to finish computing. This would give us a huge bump in performance.

Comment: so you have two issues; how to process a large file in clusters, and how to make writes to the file efficient.  I suggest you split your question into two.  Also, is the input format the same as the output format, and are you writing to the same file you are reading from, and are you writing the same size?  Note that you don't need asynchronous writes if you split your problem into separate processes - can you simply split the file into chunks first and recombine them later?

Comment: It would be really really helpful for you to provide a working example for a very small file that doesn't require chunking or asynchronous writes, perhaps upload a small input file to the web?

Comment: what do you mean 'is the way you are heading' - do you mean it's the way I'm heading, the world is heading, or how your team (who hasn't solved the problem) wants to go?

Comment: It's the way our team wants to go, sorry!

Thank you very much for your help...I will upload a file in the afternoon once I discuss with my project advisor.

Some answers:

1/ The input format is the same as the output format. Read an image, write the same image with some processing done. 

2/ We are writing to different files. The processing seems to be working well with 'mmap' and 'snow' functions.

3/ That is a good point about the recombination. I am not really sure why we are not doing that!

In any case, I will upload a file by today evening. 

Thanks again for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score -1):

probably you can use

```
sink("filename.any_extension")
```

so using this will output the result in the textfile as soon as it receives from command and further to process your result one can tuse

```
readLines("filename.any_extension",n=-1,warn=TRUE).
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This does not answer the question (which is clarified in the comments on the question).

Comment: Common. are you serious ? R work in asynchronous way. In the sink the output is added insyncronously and one can definitely use the file appended by sink by other command such as readLines or Scan kind of.

Comment: Read the comments. OP is talking about image files not text, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: OMG. This is funny .seriously !!. I have edited my answer based on you r comment . Hope this helps you SIR.